# Django - get current user permissions in a view?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to get the current logged on users permissions

My current attempt below returns an error

```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=User.id)
```

Error

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

does anyone know how I can do this? is there a simpler way?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the error because `User` is the user model. You should use `request.user` to access the logged-in user.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Individual permissions
    permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    # Permissions that the user has via a group
    group_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(group__user=request.user)
```

You should probably check that the user is logged in (e.g. use `login_required`).

Note and that the user may have permissions because of a group that they are in, or because they are a superuser (which is equivalent to having all permissions).

Answer (score 5):

Also in Django 3.0 or above, according to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_user_permissions) you can use:

```
self.request.user.get_user_permissions()
```

> Returns a set of permission strings that the user has directly.

or to get all permissions:

```
self.request.user.get_all_permissions()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just updating @Alasdair answer for other users looking to do in oneline,

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

# All permissions
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(group__user=user)).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to put restrictions using group permissions, you can use the below decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
```

Now you can use it to check if user is in a group.

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('Utilization.can_edit_invoice'))
@login_required
def edit_invoice(request, invoice_pk):
    invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=invoice_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddInvoiceForm(request.POST, instance=invoice)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(invoice.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = forms.AddInvoiceForm(instance=invoice)
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'Invoice/add_invoice.html', args)
```